# How to change working directory via extension in Adobe brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

Given a file or path - I can use FileUtils (or similar) to work with files. I'd like to be able to alter the current working directory in my extension.

I see in node.js there is `process.chdir(directory)` but I am unable to access that object.

Is there any other way to change the current working directory.

I am trying to create a simple plugin that when you open the file dialog, the directory your file listing is the same as the currently opened file.  The simple implementation being:

```
MainViewManager.on("currentFileChange", function (e, newFile) { 
  process.chdir(newFile.parentPath); // This is my FAIL
});
```

Comment: I tend to work with files that in in many different directories at the same time. But when I want to open a new file, the file I want to open is in the same directory as I am currently in. (or very close). 

Think java files in different packages, vs css files vs js files. They are all in different directories. So I'd rather ctrl+F, type part of the file and use auto complete in the file dialog and be done instead of use a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets, like many GUI apps, doesn't use the current working directory very much once it's up and running. So there is probably a different way to accomplish what you're looking for.

When you say...

> when you open the file dialog, the directory your file listing is the same as the currently opened file.

...do you mean you want the *file tree* on the left side of the window to change?  If so, try the `ProjectManager.openProject()` API.

...or do you mean you want to open a file-picker dialog box (like what you see when you choose *File > Open* in the menu)?  If so, you can use `FileSystem.showOpenDialog()` - the 4th argument is the directory to show when the dialog is first opened.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at cracking this nut a different way.